# Sortable is not working with foundation

Tags: jquery-ui, zurb-foundation, jquery-ui-sortable

Working straight from the jqueryUI [example](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#empty-lists), using foundation4 (only including jquery in the head). Has any one else had this problem? My lists are not drag-drop-sortable.

**in the head**

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3 { margin: 0; padding: 0; float: left; margin-right: 10px; background: #eee; padding: 5px; width: 143px;}
  #sortable1 li, #sortable2 li, #sortable3 li { margin: 5px; padding: 5px; font-size: 1.2em; width: 120px; }
  </style>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "ul" ).sortable({
          connectWith: "ul"
          dropOnEmpty: false
        });

        $( "#sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3" ).disableSelection();
      });
    </script>
```

**in the body** (using django...sorry for the funky template tags)

```
    <div class="large-4 columns">
        <ul id="sortable1">
            <li>Nathan</li>
            <li>Bob</li>
            <li>Joe</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 columns">
        <ul id="sortable2">

        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 columns">
        <ul id="sortable3">

        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- <script src="{% static "js/vendor/jquery.js" %}"></script> -->
    <script src="{% static "js/foundation.min.js" %}"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).foundation();
    </script>
```

Comment: add the code that you have tried so far.

Comment: It's just the sample code. I'll add it.

Comment: I guess I did put the lists in divs...

Answer (score 0):

The order I included everything was wrong.

The **body** should look like this...

```
<script src="{% static "js/vendor/jquery.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "js/foundation.min.js" %}"></script>
<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>

        $( "ul" ).sortable({
            connectWith: "ul"
            dropOnEmpty: false
        });


        $( "#sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3" ).disableSelection();

</script>
```